# Plone Error After Migration: KeyError('language',)

Tags: database, migration, plone

I have a Plone database compatible with version 3.2.2. I ran Plone version 4.3 in a docker image and upgraded (to 4.3). The migration completed successfully (or at least a message I got at the end claimed so). Then I attempted to visit the site and got the errors below. BW, when I tried version 6.0 nothing worked, so I used the oldest version of Plone I could find in a public docker image...

Is there a tool (or a mechanism) that applies fixes to the database so that it can be loaded, even in a partial way?
(I have no experience dealing with the server and very little as a client...)

On the front end ():

```
KeyError('language',) (Also, the following error occurred while attempting to render the standard error message, please see the event log for full details: language)
```

On the server side:

```
  Module zope.tales.tales, line 696, in evaluate
   - URL: main_template
   - Line 5, Column 0
   - Expression: <PathExpr standard:u'language'>
   - Names:
      {'container': <PloneSite at /CGALtau>,
       'context': <ATDocument at /CGALtau/cgal-at-tel-aviv-university>,
       'default': <object object at 0x7f51ab8bd7e0>,
       'here': <ATDocument at /CGALtau/cgal-at-tel-aviv-university>,
       'loop': {},
       'nothing': None,
       'options': {'args': ()},
       'repeat': <Products.PageTemplates.Expressions.SafeMapping object at 0x7f51a06679b0>,
       'request': <HTTPRequest, URL=http://localhost:8080/CGALtau/cgal-at-tel-aviv-university/document_view>,
       'root': <Application at >,
       'template': <FSPageTemplate at /CGALtau/document_view used for /CGALtau/cgal-at-tel-aviv-university>,
       'traverse_subpath': [],
       'user': <PropertiedUser 'admin'>}
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 217, in __call__
  Module Products.PageTemplates.Expressions, line 147, in _eval
  Module zope.tales.expressions, line 118, in _eval
KeyError: 'language'
```

Comment: Please ask your question to the Plone community: https://community.plone.org/

Comment: It's hard to say what's going wrong without more context.

There error suggests that the error happens in the `main_template` but the original 4.3.x main template defines a language:
https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/4.3.x/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_templates/main_template.pt#L15

And the ATContentTypes document view, no language is used at all:
https://github.com/plone/Products.ATContentTypes/blob/master/Products/ATContentTypes/skins/ATContentTypes/document_view.pt

Are those templates customized? It would help if you could show them.

Comment: As far as I know none of the templates are customized. All I know is that while using version 3.2.2 something happened to the database that prevents upgrading the database to a higher version.

Comment: My intended question is how to fix the database (and not how to fix plone), so that it  can be loaded, even in a partial way. I merely want access to the content that is not damaged. (I slightly rephrased the question asked.)

Comment: Instead of customizing document_view, you could go to `[SITE_URL]/portal_types/manage_main`, choose `Document` and set the default view to `base_view`.

Comment: It redeirects  me to [SITE_URL]/acl_users/credentials_cookie_auth/require_login?came_from=http%3A//localhost%3A8080/CGALtau/portal_types/manage_main, and I get the same error...

Comment: Do you see your data in zope catalog? Try: adding en-us to you site languages, adding 'language' to metadata via zope. I run into similar issues every time I run plone 4 => 6 migration pipelines.

Comment: I only see a link to the site via my browser on http://localhost:8080/. When I click the link I get the errors. Is there a URL I can use to see the zope catalog?

Comment: After some pocking, I'm able to see something under [SITE]/manage_main. Any hint on how to continue from here is appreciated...

Comment: You could look in [SITE]/manage_main/portal_skins/custom, if there is a customized main_template.pt and rename it to backup_main_template.pt, to see if the error disappears, although it could be in another skin folder, not only in 'custom'. To counter proof that the maintemplate is the problem, try calling http://localhost:8080/CGALtau/cgal-at-tel-aviv-university/base_view

Comment: localhost:8080/CGALtau/cgal-at-tel-aviv-university/base_view gives the same error (KeyError('language',) ...). 
There is no [SITE]/manage_main/portal_skins/custom, but there is http://localhost:8080/CGALtau/portal_skins/custom/manage_main, but there is no *.pl there.

Comment: Some template is expecting a variable 'language', which is not defined. You can use `[SITE_URL]/portal_skins/manage_findForm` and enter 'language' in the "contains"-field, to try to find the template, or customize the main template and add an additinal definition of 'language' there, the same way 'lang' is defined. If you have access to the filesystem (and ideally a copy of the site to ruin everything in a safe way), you could also write a browser view, to export the content. Another reason could be multilinguality and add-ons like LinguaPlone be involved.

Answer (score 2):

With an uncustomized standard main_template and the base_view, no error should happen.
Maybe there's an addon installed, which overrides the main_template.

As you write you want to merely access content, that would be also possible with an export via the GenericSetup tool:
Call `[SITE_URL]/portal_setup/manage_exportSteps` in a browser, search for 'Content', check the box next to it, scroll down to the end of the page and click 'Export selected steps'.

Also you can access the site from the commandline, by adding a script in the ZOPE instance's directory (where `buildout.cfg` lives, too)
and run it like that: `./bin/instance run yourscript.py`, the Zope object (parent of the Plone site) is then available as the variable `app`[1],
so if your site's id is 'Plone', you could access it with `app['Plone']`

It takes some time until the script finishes, because all modules are loaded. You can add a breakpoint in the script for an interactive inspection, to play around without the need to run the whole script after each change: `from pdb import set_trace; set_trace()`

For the records, here's a recipe on how to do it with even older versions:
http://web.archive.org/web/20070302234456/http://zopelabs.com/cookbook/1054240694/1054240694

[1] https://zope.readthedocs.io/en/latest/operation.html#id4